# Surprising behaviour on Stack Overflow website

Tags: discussion, support, product-support

Today I found this surprising behaviour on all my questions on Stack Overflow.

Suddenly I see most of my questions are downvoted. I'm not sure why. After some time, some of the questions got upvotes.
I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

Is this a Stack Overflow algorithm or can any other user be doing this?!!

Comment: Short answer: It's almost certainly a human misbehaving, not an algorithm.  Wait 24 hours and it should be automatically fixed.

Comment: You made a new friend. It means that you are leaving a mark on the site. :) Keep it up!

Comment: The punishments are not strong enough to combat this toxic behavior.  I am in favor of an automated cool down, a cease and desist message, and the system neutralizing these blatant abuses instead of reversing them.  The attackers quickly learn of the reversal and merely repeat the attack on a smaller scale and/or pace the same attack out over a longer period of time.  This ruins Stack Overflow.

Comment: You did indeed get 16 downvotes today from another user. They should be automatically invalidated by a script within 24-48 hours. If they're not, please raise a flag for moderator attention and we'll have them invalidated manually. Sometimes this kind of thing happens; it's best not to lose too much sleep over it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I could not find a proposal to increase the punishment for serial downvoting. Has this been discussed on Meta before?

Comment: @E_net4isoutofclosevotes I get very, very cranky when serial downvoting affects the answers that I carefully craft.  Just this week, it happened again.  A set of my posts were serial DV'ed, the system reversed it, and then the 2nd wave came.  I don't care about unicorn points any more.  What I do care about is the vote tally telling an untrue tale about the quality/correctness of my advice -- which some users will not be able to determine on their own.  I have whinged on Meta before, but it just gets DV'ed to oblivion, so I don't bother saying anything.

Comment: By neutralizing the DV's, the attackers cannot re-DV the same posts and the attacked user gets a +8 rep per DV in the series.  I don't know how to migitate the possibility that sockpuppets could be used to serial DV, then the system would "overpay" the recipient.  I don't have a perfect suggestion about how to better handle voting abuse, but I do know that something new needs to be done because it damages the perception of the content here and misleads researchers.

Comment: I understand the sentiment, @mickmackusa. The way I see it, one might just need to phrase the proposal in a neutral manner with all relevant pieces of evidence that makes the change important. The only problem I can think of it is accidentally shaming a user who did not know better and chose to seriously and serially rate a user's posts (not sure how often this happens even).

Comment: Accidentally committing serial downvoting? Never heard of it. As for someone posting an eloquent Meta post -- I am not that guy. I tend to call a spade a front-end loader, so I'll defer to someone who is better equipped to address the Meta community. I think I would be happy if the system would just give an upvote worth +2 rep to neutralize the DVs and ban the user -- this would solve the "overpaying" problem.  There is no "shaming" done. The serial DVer would be cooled down and privately messaged.  The abused user would simply see +2 on the attacked posts. Serial UVs could simply be reversed.

Comment: @mickmackusa this really doesn’t happen that often. And in most cases, it ends with the automated reversal; the perpetrator’s emotional energy that led to the spree has been spent. If you are being targeted more than once, send us a custom flag and we can take a look it someone needs a chat from us. Using socks to do the downvoting is actually rare; the primary motivations for sock accounts are to stave off a question ban and to make your own rep look good towards the outside world, not to facilitate revenge.

Comment: I am not going to add more flags to you queue. @MartijnPieters  You have bigger fish to fry.  My mention of sockpuppets being strategically used was a hypothetical pertaining to my suggestion to give +10 for every serial DV.  We can dismiss that now.  +2 would be enough and would make socketpuppet serial voting useless.

Comment: @mickmackusa people that abuse the system by targeting are the bigger fish.

Comment: @mickmackusa 'Accidentally committing serial downvoting', lol, 'I accidentally robbed 12 convenience stores - nobody told me it was wrong':)